# VFS2 Error cannot delete file and could not get the groups id of the current user (error code: -1)

Tags: java, sftp, vfs, apache-commons-vfs

I'm using VFS2 to take and import files into the folders by SFTP protocol.
But I'm obtaining an Error. Picture below my code:
[image]

Into the log for all files I'm watching this error:

[image]

The error sequence is:
1) cannot delete file 
2) Could not determine if file
3) Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Could not get the groups id of the current user (error code: -1)

Properties folder:
[image]

Could it dependens on the owner/groups ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/VFS-617 (also applies to isReadable).

The root cause of the issue is one of two things - either the SFTP server doesn't allow commands to be executed ("exec") by the client; or the SFTP server is missing the "id" command (e.g. it's a Windows server).

A git pull request has been raised here: https://github.com/apache/commons-vfs/pull/27 but it requires unit tests before it will be included in VFS.